# Regular expression to match honorific title followed by full name

Tags: python, string, list

Given a file 'funeral.txt' write a regular expression for people names that is triggered by honorifics (Mr, Ms, Senator, etc).

I have so far written the code

```
import re
file = open("funeral.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()
honorific_names = "([M][a-z\.]{2,4})\s+([A-Z][a-z]*[\.\-\']*)*"
re.findall(honorific_names, text)
```

This gives me the output as

```
[('Mrs.', 'Meghan'), ('Mrs.', 'Oprah'), ('Mr.', 'Boris'), ('Ms.', 'Megan')]
```

However what I am looking for is:

```
['Mrs. Meghan', 'Mrs. Oprah Winfrey', 'Mr. Boris Johnson', 'Ms. Megan Specia']
```

How exactly should I modify the pattern ?

---

**Some text from funeral.txt**

```
The service also came just weeks after he and his wife, Mrs. Meghan, the Duchess of Sussex, gave a bombshell interview to Mrs. Oprah Winfrey in which they laid bare their problems with the royal family

According to Mr. Boris Johnson, the whole of United Kingdom are sadden by the passing of Prince Philip.  

— Ms. Megan Specia
```

Comment: I think this is quite impossible to answer without some example rows from the `funeral.txt` file. Please edit your question to include some sample data :)

Comment: Can you share the string input ?

Comment: @NiclasLindqvist I would agree in most cases, but that is just a string post-processing to achieve

Comment: The code provided does not seem to cover the example of honorific title "Senator", but if @Zara K is happy with the result then yes, joining the pairs would be suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`honorific_names = r'((?:Mrs|Mr|Ms|Senator|Sr|Dr)\.?\s(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*)'`

I think this would at least check out on your sample text, should be easy enough to expand on for your extended need. It's not the cleanest solution maybe, one could compact the Mr/Ms/Mrs but for readability it makes sense I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `" ".join` on each pair to make one string

```
[" ".join(x) for x in [('Mrs.', 'Meghan'), ('Mrs.', 'Oprah'), ('Mr.', 'Boris'), ('Ms.', 'Megan')]]
['Mrs. Meghan', 'Mrs. Oprah', 'Mr. Boris', 'Ms. Megan']
```

```
import re

with open("funeral.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()
result = [" ".join(x) for x in re.findall(r"([M][a-z.]{2,4})\s+([A-Z][a-z]*[.\-\']*)*", text)]
```

Comment: I have added a part of the text. However it is not just the join that I am looking for. The pattern only matches until the first name. I want to include the full name